# Cache object does not appear to be set

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

Please see the code below:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Using outputFile As New IO.StreamWriter("c:\log.txt", True)
            outputFile.WriteLine("Got here")
        End Using
        If Request.QueryString("id") = "1" Then
            TextBox1.Text = "id1"
        ElseIf Request.QueryString("id") = "2" Then
            TextBox1.Text = "id2"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the code below:

```
Public Class Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private Sub page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load
        SendPageRequest()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SendPageRequest()
        Dim proxy As New Net.WebProxy
        Dim webReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:58722/Default.aspx?id=1"), Net.HttpWebRequest)
        If proxy IsNot Nothing Then webReq.Proxy = proxy
        Using webResp As Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(webReq.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)
            'Get the response, then close it as we don't actually need anything but   to send the request.
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the code below (default.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Caching._Default" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>


    <asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

I first navigate to: test.aspx, then to default.aspx.

I do not pass any querystring parameters to default.aspx when I access it (after accessing test.aspx).  However, the textbox is empty suggesting that the cache is not set when I access test.aspx.  Why is this?

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks.  I have updated the question.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.100).aspx), it should be `Duration="60"`, i.e. with double-quotes.

Comment: @Andrew Morton, I have added the double quotes.  However, it still completely ignores the cache.